# Handling LDAP server is unavailable

Tags: c#, asp.net, ldap

```
private void BindSearchedUser(string Domain, string UserName)
    {
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain);
    .
    .
    .
```

If I provide some invalid Domain name, after executing the first line it throws an exception **PrincipalServerDownException was unhandled by usercode**.

Error Details: The LDAP server is unavailable.

How can I check the Domain is valid or not before executing that line So that I can Show a error msg instead of throwing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your line in a `try` block to catch `PrincipalServerDownException`, which is the exception thrown when the server cannot be reached:

```
private void BindSearchedUser(string Domain, string UserName)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Domain);
    } 
    catch (PrincipalServerDownException ex)
    {
        // show your error message
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```